Controlling the confounding effect on cross sectional data analysis
I have a cross-sectional study in which an effect (feature) is analyzed in multiple groups of disease severity status.
All groups may have individuals with shared characteristics like age and sex, which could confound the observed variable.
Knowing that no control (healthy) subjects are available, how can we isolate or assess the effect of those confounding factors on the observed variable in the different disease severity groups? Conversely, is there a way to analyze whether the confounding factors had a causal relationship (in addition to or instead of the disease itself) with the observed variable?
Thanks for your help in advance!
